# Send Google Cloud Error Reporting emails to a Group email list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I am using the Error Reporting functionality inside Google Cloud.

Is there a way to send email notifications to an arbitrary email address ?

Or at least, to a Google Group email list ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, email notifications only get sent to the account address. As a workaround you can implement mail forwarding rules that will forward to the correct desired address based on the email subject and contents.
Thanks for using Stackdriver Error Reporting!

Comment: To be more precise:
You can forward these emails to an email alias (or to a [Slack channel](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/206819278-Send-emails-to-Slack)) by using [Gmail's forward feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957) and the following filter:
`from:(PlatformNotifications-noreply@google.com) subject:("New Error")`.

Comment: @Amir Hermelin, by reading Google Cloud documentation on Notifications (cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications) it seems that this is still not possible. Could you please confirm?